# Regarding moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

The moment.js takes a number as a date.
For example, if I input 201, I get              "01-01-0201 00:00:00".  I want 201 to be displayed if I attempt to edit. 
My approach is;

```
if (moment(data, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS').isValid()) {
    console.log('data if in date format: ' + angular.toJson(data));
    return moment(data).format('MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:SS');
} else {
    console.log('data if not in date format: ' + angular.toJson(data));
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Help me understand this part, "where as I want 201 to be displayed if I go for edit". Here is what I understand from it, you want moment to format on valid date objects and not numbers? ie, 201 should be left as 201 and not converted into a date string?

Comment: Meaning, while creating i have a field where i can give number like 201 or a date with time. And when i again go to edit the same, it should show me the exact value.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this expression

```
moment(data, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS').isValid()
```

should return false if data is incomplete, but Moment is very forgiving by default. You may specify the last argument in constructor to enable strict parsing:

```
moment('201', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS', true).isValid() //false
moment('01-01-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS', true).isValid() //false
moment('01-01-2016 12:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS', true).isValid() //true
```

Comment: Yes, "strict parsing" helped. @SphDev.

Comment: @NarasinghaPadhi, welcome to Stack Overflow! if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. You could also find a few useful tips how to use this resource here: [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [About] page